# Fetched data from GraphCMS using GraphQL in a NextJS project keeps retuning undefined values

Tags: next.js, graphql, graphcms

I'm trying to use NextJS and GraphQL to fetch some data from GraphCMS to a page located at `pages/writing.js`. The problem is, doesn't matter what I do I get errors like `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`.

I've been trying to fix this nonstop for the past few hours. All guides — both written and video — do things a lot different so I'm feeling kinda lost and without a clear north. I always manage to get to the end of such guides but the error is always there.

When I go to my content API link provided by GraphCMS it works just fine as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image]

This is what my `package.json` dependencies look like just in case it's relevant:

```
"dependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^7.3.6",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.0.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^12.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
```

And finally this is what the `writing.js` component looks like:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../components/home/Header";

import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request";

const Writing = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>{posts.title}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default Writing;

const url =
  "[my content api]";

const client = new GraphQLClient(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer [my permanent auth token]`,
  },
});

const query = gql`
  query MyQuery {
    postsConnection {
      edges {
        node {
          date
          id
          slug
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export function GraphQLRequest() {
  const getPosts = async () => {
    const variables = { title };
    const response = await client.request(query, variables);
    console.log("RESPONSE FROM GRAPHQL-REQUEST API CALL", response);
  };

  return {
    props: { title },
  };
}
```

I would appreciate some guidance on how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix get it working by using Apollo and GraphQL. This is the final code. Hopefully this will help someone in the future. I recommend the GraphCMS and GraphQL video from James Q Quick as well.

```
import client from "../apolloClient";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export default function Writing(posts) {
  return (
    <>

    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data :posts } = await client.query({
    query: gql `
      query Posts {
        posts {
          id
          slug
          title
        }
        postsConnection {
          edges {
            node {
              content {
                raw
              }
              coverImage {
                url
              }
              date
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });
  console.log(posts);

  return{
    props: {
      posts
    }
  }
}
```